# Understanding LC_COLLATE. Is it also used for setting character range?

Tags: macos, sed, zsh, locale

I had a special character(Â) which gave error while using sed.

```bash
echo $'H\xc3\x82Bnc' | sed -E 's/[A-Z]*/`&`/g'
sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence

$ locale
LANG=""
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

Now if I set LC_COLLATE, then the command works.

```bash
echo $'H\xc3\x82Bnc' | LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8" sed -E 's/[A-Z]*/`&`/g'
`HÂB`n``c``
```

Is LC_COLLATE affecting the character range. Why after LC_COLLATE was set, did the code produce no error of illegal byte sequence? I'm using MacOS and the sed is implemented from FreeBSD in it.

Comment: It's there in the first code block.

Comment: Och my eyes I'm blind.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> LC_COLLATE. Is it also used for setting character range?

Yes.

> Is LC_COLLATE affecting the character range

Yes.

> Why after LC_COLLATE was set, did the code produce no error of illegal byte sequence?

Because you set encoding to UTF-8 intead of C.

LC_COLLATE sets the character range for collation i.e. comparison of characters and strings. So earlier the LC_COLLATE was set to `C` and it couldn't compare `Â` with other characters but after setting LC_COLLATE to `en_US.UTF-8`, it could compare successfully.

Also, the backtick (`) appeared on the whole `HÂB` since sometimes the accented characters are treated same as their base characters (*so A and Â were same here*).

Comment: Can you provide any reference link? Why is the behaviour of LC_COLLATE as such?

Comment: Is it possible that instead of affecting character range, LC_COLLATE was affecting the sequence of the characters? Like it was sorting them in some fashion? Since it is used for sorting, this seems more plausible.

Comment: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html . What are you trying to do? I agree that it's confusing - there is LC_CTYPE and LC_COLLATE, and LC_COLLATE is used by regex.h . I do not know if this would count as a bug, but the question is why not just use `C.UTF-8`.

Comment: `sed` in my case says the following in its documentation. `The COLUMNS, LANG, LC_ALL, LC_CTYPE and LC_COLLATE environment variables affect the execution of sed as described in environ(7)`. The `environ` man page says `LC_COLLATE - Locale to be used for ordering of strings` and  `LC_CTYPE  -  Locale to be used for character classification (letter, space, digit, etc.) and for interpreting byte sequences as multibyte characters`. So is my terminal not following it's own documentation.

Comment: I was just trying to put `\`` around some sequence while I encountered this error. If I use `C.UTF-8` it prints `\`H\`?\`\`?\`B\`n\`\`c\`\`` which doesn't take care of multibyte sequence

Comment: Hey I just wanted to confirm that there is no chance of any kind of shuffling of bytes taking place? It's just because the man pages in my system speak differently, so it's hard to digest. Also could you tell where does LC_COLLATE does it's sorting stuff, like ranges and all?